# How declaring variable to global? with case foreach? Javascript

Tags: javascript

How declaring a global variable in function?

try check : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Blackarch/17hxsa9r/4/)

1. I use `foreach()` for `checkbox`.
2. IF variable `id` not declare then declare `var id` (and add some data(id&value) to boxval // *this not important / you can ignore this*).
3. after that go up and repeated again`(foreach)`.
4. for second repeated (what i expect is variable ID already declare in first code(No 2)), (because, id already declare it's go to `else`).

I try use alert to determine the flow of code running.

PHP :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="A" class="box-1" id="ID_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="B" class="box-1" id="ID_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="C" class="box-2" id="ID_2"> 
<input type="checkbox" value="D" class="box-2" id="ID_2">

<input type="button" id="button" />
```

JS:

```
$('#button').bind('click', function() {

    var boxval="";
    $("input[class^='box-']").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            if (typeof window.id == "undefined" || window.id == null)
            {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert('a');
                boxval += $(this).attr('id') +'=&' + $(this).attr('value');
            }
            else
            {
                if(id == $(this).attr('id'))
                {
                    boxval += '&' + $(this).attr('value');
                    alert('b');
                }
                else
                {
                    boxval += $(this).attr('id') +'=&' + $(this).attr('value');
                    alert('c');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    alert(boxval)
});
```

Try to checked the first & second checkbox if it's correct will be alert `a,b` and `ID_1=&A&B`.

Comment: define it in the global scope, and you can assign value in the function.

Comment: You can add global variable by adding properties to window like `window.foo = "hello"`

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? Looks a lot like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Defining globals is really bad practise.

Comment: @Yoshi i just try to checking, if thy same ID then just add value, if different add another ID & value.

Comment: The quesiton is why you want to collect those values? What part of your code will later use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `var` than you saying that this variable is local is particular scope.

To create global variable you can use `window.id = $(this).attr('id');`

---

You have repeating ID's in your HTML, that is not valid and jQuery will not find second ID element.

Better use `<input type="checkbox" value="A" class="box-1" data-id="ID_1">` and `$('.box-1').data('id')`

Comment: That what i expect thx a lot, ow okay thx for your suggestion.